# Macbook Pro - Turn off display with the lid open for High Sierra

Tags: screen, macbook-pro

What is the command line equivalent to do this for High Sierra? I'm referencing this thread here that had it working on Yosemite.

[Turn off MacBook Pro's display while connected to external monitor on Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152203/turn-off-macbook-pros-display-while-connected-to-external-monitor-on-yosemite)

The following no longer works:

sudo nvram boot-args=niog=1

Comment: Try tip#2 on this page, it isn't command line, but it should work: https://www.cultofmac.com/176329/turn-off-internal-lcd-display-of-your-macbook-air-os-x-tips/

Comment: This didn't work for me, I tried this and it turns both screens off.