# How to automatically turn black main monitor when external monitor is connected while using internal keyboard

Tags: display

When I use external display, I always use screen mirroring and set main display brightness to zero.

Macbook remembers screen mirroring config, but I must turn down the brightness manually every time the monitor is connected.

Is there a way to turn off main monitor automatically when external monitor is connected?

There are similar questions, but the first answer is about clamshell mode, and the second question's answers doesn't match my need. Because I want to brightness down automatically.

[Turn off the macbook main display while working with monitor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269853/turn-off-the-macbook-main-display-while-working-with-monitor)

[How do I turn off laptop display when I have an external display?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21729/how-do-i-turn-off-laptop-display-when-i-have-an-external-display)

Comment: We don’t ask new questions on the same topic because another is old. It would be best to edit in precisely how your situation isn’t the same as the old question. Showing how your problem is different make is less likely it will be closed as a duplicate

Comment: I changed reason "old" to "doesn't match my need".

Comment: Detailing [how existing posts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152203/turn-off-macbook-pros-display-while-connected-to-external-monitor-on-yosemite) don’t meet your needs [would be best](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56839/how-to-disable-macbook-pro-internal-display-when-using-external-monitors)

Comment: @bmike I want to brightness down automatically. All the answers indicate manually. Is there answer that I oversee?